# Updating the attributes in the rails errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am looking to update the model errors hash that the rails sent with humanized attributes name. For example for a model called `Foo` . I have an attribute called `foo_nm` . I want the translated to foo_name when I do `@foo.errors` assuming that `@foo` is an object of class Foo.

```
{"foo_nm"=>["can't be blank"]}
```

So far I tried to extend the human_attribute_name the following way

```
   HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :foo_nm => "foo_name"
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end
```

But this doesnt seem to modify the errors hash. Any ideas around on how I can update the errors hash would be appreciated

Comment: Can't you use `@foo.errors.add(:foo_name, 'error message')`? And then extract the errors not matching your attributes' names `foo_nm`, etc?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I am using validates :foo_nm , presence: true and according to you will have to rewrite the validates just to add the foo_name in the error hash . That is something that i dont want to do bcoz i have 10 other models like foo where I need _nm to be _name. so i will have to change it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it inside your locale files?

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  hello: "Hello world"
  activerecord:
    models:
      foo: "Foo"
    attributes:
      foo_nm: "foo_name"
```

Comment: This is one of the first thing i tried and it seems like locale translations are taken into account only when you do foo.errors.full_messages and not on foo.errors .